# variable '__deleted_0' of type 'System.Boolean' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined" in LINQKit

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linqkit

I have some troubles with using **LINQKit** library in order to include dynamic filters in my queries.

---

To begin with, I would like to share with a type of filter that is being sent to my query:

```
public Expression<Func<JobSpecificationDetail,bool>> Criteria { get; set; }
```

---

Next, I have my query which simply executes the following piece of code:

```
var queryTest = applicantCacheRepo
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(a => a.Profile)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.ProfileEmployer)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.Employer)
            .Include(a => a.ProfileApplicationDetail)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.ApplicationStatusSysCodeUnique)
            .Include(a => a.Person)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.PersonDetail)
            .Include(a => a.JobSpecification)
            .ThenInclude(j => j.JobSpecificationDetail)
            .Where(a => filters.ManagerFilter.Invoke(a.Profile)
                        && filters.ApplyDateFilter.Invoke(a.ProfileApplicationDetail)
                        && filters.StatusDateFilter.Invoke(a.ProfileApplicationDetail)
                        && filters.IsTopFilter.Invoke(a.ProfileApplicationDetail)
                        && !a.ProfileApplicationDetail.ApplicationStatusSysCodeUnique.Deleted
                        && a.Person.Deleted == false
                        && a.Profile.Deleted == false
                        && a.JobSpecification.JobSpecificationDetail
                                .Any(jd=>filters.JobSpecificationDetailSpec.Criteria.Invoke(jd)) //this line results in aforementioned exception
                        && a.Profile.ProfileTypeSysCodeUniqueId == SysCodeUniqueId.ProfileType.EmployeeApplicant
                        && !a.ProfileApplicationDetail.Deleted
            ).OrderByDescending(a => a.ApplyDate);
```

So, here in the query, the part which is indicated with a comment, throws that exception. I do not know what to do. In the query, you can find implementation of **LINQKit** methods as well. They do not create any problems.

Comment: sounds like a pending migration

Comment: @MorenajeRD could you please explain which migration do you mean? And also, I would be very grateful if you could give me any directions in this situation

Comment: Something wrong with one filter. Find which one by commenting out code.